# Django-Summernote: Working fine on local machine but server not posting the data

Tags: django, summernote

I am using Django-summernote for my project. It works perfectly on local system. But on server (Nginx+gunicorn) it is not updating the data.
I mean widget loads properly. Image are also uploaded to server, but it throws 404 error upon submission.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common problem that many Django users will have. The issue was with one of the Slugfield. Need to specify max length otherwise it will show errors.